# how to fix Error: Port conflict: another instance is already running

Tags: 12.04, postgresql, database

- I fired two command

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get upgrade
  ```
- It will give me error after upgrade(after press "Y")

  ```
      Setting up postgresql-9.1 (9.1.19-0ubuntu0.12.04) ...
       * Starting PostgreSQL 9.1 database server                                       
       * Error: Port conflict: another instance is already running on /var/run/postgresql with port 5432
                                                                               [fail]
      invoke-rc.d: initscript postgresql, action "start" failed.
      dpkg: error processing postgresql-9.1 (--configure):
       subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
      Errors were encountered while processing:
       postgresql-9.1
      E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
  ```
- I have try so much thread but can't get solution please help

Answer (score 0):

In this case, there are postgresql that already running. You need to switch if off:

`sudo service postgresql stop`

Then:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

To make sure nothing is bound on port 5432, do `netstat -ntulp|grep 5432`.

Comment: When i stop the postgresql its gives me ERROR "Error: pid file is invalid, please manually kill the stale server process [fail]"

Comment: then kill it manually. `kill -9 <pid>`.

Comment: ill try with `pkill -9 <pid>` but no any effect

Comment: best is to `chkconfig postresql off`, reboot the server to clean anything that hanging and try again.